# Substitute bootstrap indicatores with font awesome icones

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I'm using the bootstrap carousel and trying to change the indicators, **not the left and right buttons**, to use fontawesome icones, I want to use the 'f05d' or fa-check-circle-o icone when is not active and 'f058' or fa-check-circle when is active.

I tried using the example in font awesome site:(without success)

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>can be used</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>as bullets</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-square"></i>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

I tried this in css

```
ul { padding-left:20px; list-style:none; }
li:before {    
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f067';
    margin:0 5px 0 -15px;
}
```

and it just add the icones on the left it dont't substitute the icones.

http://jsfiddle.net/2q5059y0/

Comment: the indicators are nested in the <ol> tags so you should just style the <ol> accordingly as I see you are using ul instead

Comment: In my code even if I change from ul to ol it still dont change the default icones and the font awesome icone appear in the left side of the page

Comment: Can you paste the part in the header where you linked the stylesheet

Comment: And remove the fa class from the ul

Comment: Allready try that... the fontwesome icones appear on the left... you can see that in the example that i give if you expande the layout area